# Make parent's pseudo opacity clip to childs border radius

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to get my parent to overlap an opacity (dimmed) style to a child element, but this child element can have different border radius' - `10px`, `50%`, etc. I am trying to make the overlay clip dynamically.

If I set it to `100%`, it works for `50%`, but breaks for `10px` and so on.

Unfortunately the HTML mark up cannot be moved around much.

Is this possible to achieve? The end result is there should be no bright red in the fiddle, as it should be completely covered by the opacity overlay.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/7nfLqpbt/1/)

Comment: why not applying the pseudo element to the child? or consider multiple background, or even box-shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in having your mark up accessible to `border-radius: inherit`

https://jsfiddle.net/7nfLqpbt/2/

Comment: this is a bit overkill .. you can simply use overflow hidden and make the pseudo element relative to the needed element